# Need for a set to have finite Lebesgue measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm reading Royden and Fitzpatrick's book (4th edition) wherein on page 44, we have the following theorem:

If $\{B_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is a descending collection of Lebesgue measurable sets and $m(B_1)<\infty$ then $m(\bigcap_{k =1}^\infty B_{k})=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}m(B_k)$.

At the end of this section, there is an exercise: Show at the assumption that $m(B_1)<\infty$ is necessary. I'm trying to find a counter example where if $m(B_1)$ is not finite, then the above equality fails to holds.

Can anyone gice any ideas as to how one would construct such a collection?

Comment: What do you mean by a descending collection? That $B_k$ is a subset of all previous $B_i$ for $i<k$?

Comment: $B_{k+1}\subset B_k$

Comment: Well then isn't it true that $\bigcap_{k =1}^n B_{k} = B_n$ so that $m(\bigcap_{k =1}^n B_{k}) = m(B_n)$ and you could just take the limit $n \to \infty$? Where's the problem? Maybe because it doesn't make sense to talk about limits when the members of the sequence are infinite?

Comment: I'm looking for a specific collection for which the theorem fails to hold because its first member, $B_1$ has infinite measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample.

Let $B_n:=[n,\infty)\subseteq\mathbb R$ for $n=1,2,\dots$

Let $m$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$.

Then $(B_n)_n$ is a descending sequence of Lebesgue measurable sets, and $B:=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n=\varnothing$.

So: $$m(B)=m(\varnothing)=0\neq+\infty=\lim_{n\to\infty}m(B_n)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried to construct a far more complex counter example.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try $B_k = [k,\infty)$ with Lebesgue measure on the line.